# East/South Asian student vs Western student quality & commitment

Tags: training

If you’ve studied martial arts in east or south Asia, is the long-term and in-class “commitment” of the average student significantly, or somewhat, higher than in the “West”?

Also, does the average student quality seem higher? Would this be because only the committed students stick with the harder lessons, or because the students give 100%?

In east/south Asia, is it like the West in that there still a number of average guys in class who aren’t all that athletic or naturally talented, and who go through class at 90%?  Or will the sifu / sensei / sabumnim whack ‘em on the back of the head if they’re not giving 100%?

Comment: This question... could probably do with some refinement.  Asia ("the Orient") is a huge place.  Even in any given country, there's a huge difference in subcultures depending on the region, whether you're in the cities or rural areas, etc.  The quality of schools, and students, is all over the board just like anywhere else.

Comment: Welcome to MA.SE! Since this isn't a discussion site, we look for questions that have answers and, as Bankuei points out, (east) Asia is very very large and what you are asking seems very dojang specific even taking that into account.

Answer (score 1):

The quality of the student is dependent on the individual rather than the place they studied at. A practitioner of martial arts can be just as mentally focused and have the same physical ability as well as the same quality instruction whether they train in Japan, Korea, or Indiana. Now what I will say is that in some styles a student is encouraged to train in full contact, or perhaps outside in a more harsh environment to test your focus. This training might be frowned upon in some circles so it's not very common, especially in the US where a Martial Arts school is a business and you don't want to drive away your students. That isn't to say that training in the US is inferior, it's not. The right student and instructor relationship will bring out your best. I don't believe it's like you see in the movies any longer where a student goofing off gets whacked with a stick.

So what I'm saying is you get out of martial arts what you put in. A student is no more likely to do better studying in Asia vs North America.

Answer (score 1):

Needle Through Brick is a documentary about traditional and modern martial arts in Malaysia. It is about the difficulties the aging generation of kung fu masters has in passing skills to the next generation in the modern, globalized world. The [Needle Through Brick trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=997aRsGSvfU) is available on YouTube. I think you will find the concerns present in the film about students, motivation, and training time are very similar to those in other parts of the world.

Hopefully this begins to answer your question.